# When to resolve by "using" declaration and when to explicitly state the namespace

Tags: .net, performance

I am using System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager only once in my entire code, and I'm wondering if it is better practice to name it explicitly rather than use a 'using' declaration.

```
string LogoUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogoURL"];
```

and

```
using System.Configuration;;
string LogoUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogoURL"];
```

Does having the 'using' declaration involve more overhead than explicitly stating the namespace e.g. does it pull in more than I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

The compiler converts all calls to a class to use the fully qualified name You can see it in the produced IL, using any decompiler.

Comment: Ah so it is just a convenience for us developers. Thanks.